# Huge memory overhead with vector of pointers

Tags: c++, heap-memory, new-operator, stdvector

Here is my code :

```
#include <vector>

class Dummy
{
   int a,z,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p;
}; //sizeof(Dummy) => 40

int main()
{
   const int nbObj = 1000000;
   {
      std::vector<Dummy> vec;
      for( int i = 0; i<nbObj; ++i)
         vec.push_back(Dummy());

      vec.shrink_to_fit();
      // Break here : ~40Mo used => OK

      vec.clear();
      vec.shrink_to_fit();
      // Break here : ~0Mo used => OK
   }
   {
      std::vector<Dummy*> vec;
      for( int i = 0; i<nbObj; ++i)
         vec.push_back(new Dummy);

      vec.shrink_to_fit();

      // Break Here : ~140Mo used => Why? (should be ~48Mo?)

      for(Dummy *ptr : vec)
         delete ptr;
      vec.clear();
      vec.shrink_to_fit();

      // Break here :  15Mo used => Why? (should be ~0Mo?)
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I just run this code in debug on Windows and break where are the comments for checking memory usage in the taskmanager. Using a vector of pointers should be the same size (+pointer size for each object) ?

Comment: `delete` doesn't necessarily return memory to the OS. Typically the application hangs on to it for future use.

Comment: `// Break here :  15Mo used => Why? (should be ~0Mo?)` -- This is why using TaskManager to figure this all out is the wrong tool.  If you want to see if there really is a memory leak, run your entire code in a `for` loop and see if the memory usage keeps increasing.  The C++ heap manager is smart enough to know to reuse memory that is now "deleted", in case another call to `new` is made -- if it didn't do that, your program would run slower.

Comment: Minor point: you could also create the vector with `std::vector<Dummy> vec(nbObj, dummy());`.

Comment: You've just discovered why allocating one memory block that's a gigabyte long is less overhead than allocating a thousand one-megabyte long blocks.

Comment: `vec.shrink_to_fit();` -- This is not guaranteed to clear the memory.

Comment: Consider trying a release build. It's possible the debug heap adds overhead to each allocation for bounds checking. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-debug-heap-details?view=msvc-170